# Cloudflare and NGINX Ingress communication

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, cloudflare

I have my domain hosted on **Cloudflare** which proxies traffic to Kubernetes NGINX Ingress (public IP address of the LoadBalancer). In the Cloudflare, I'm using the [**Full** SSL/TLS encryption mode](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes/full/). On the Ingress side, I don't have any HTTPS configuration, just HTTP as shown below:

```
$ kubectl get ing  
NAME                      CLASS   HOSTS                              ADDRESS        PORTS  
ingress-sample            nginx   xyz.domain.com                     A.B.C.D         80
```

In the Cloudflare [documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes/full/), I see that in the **Full** mode, communication between Cloudflare and Origin server is also encrypted.

[image]

Should I configure HTTPS in the Ingress config or does Cloudflare do it out-of-the-box?